# Swift swipe-able views

Tags: ios, uiview, swift

I'm new to Swift and iOS development, and am looking to set up a series of views, or "cards", that can be swiped left and right, with the next/previous cards remaining at the edges to indicate that they are there. This is done in iOS App Store previews:

[image: App store preview]

So far all I've really found is this Medium article: [iOS Swift: Swipe View](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swipe-view-with-swift-44fa83a2e078/). However I'm not sure if this is the right way to do what I'm asking above, and I also don't know how to get the next/previous cards to remain at the edges on each swipe.

Does anyone have any tips for achieving this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way will be to use `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.
`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is provided out of the box and is very powerful.

**Basically you need:**

1. Add `UICollectionView` to your view controller.
2. By default `UICollectionView` goes with `Flow` layout selected.
3. Configure `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

   - Set scroll direction to Horizontal
   - Define item size and spacing. Keep in mind that you need just one item to be fully visible; in addition spaces to the left and right should be visible as well; further more you need to show pieces of previous and next cards, so some basic math waiting for you:). One small trick to make you very first and very last cards be centered properly: you should specify vertical section insets to be equal to the sum of visible width of previous card plus space between cards.

Steps above should be enough to have vertically scrollable cards view. But it will not look great! To make it great you probably need perfectly to center most appropriate card after user end scrolling. **To achieve sticky scrolling** you need to work with the following `UICollectionViewDelegate` methods:

```
// compute collection view content offset in method bellow
override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    ...
}

// compute targetContentOffset in method bellow 
override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    ...
}
```

... last hint: to make collection view deceleration look quick in code of your view controller do:

```
self.collectionView?.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
```

**Paging indicator:**

In example that you provide there is a paging control that reflects current item and overall items count. You need to add `UIPageControll` manually; you can do it in storyboard. The best place to update page control state will be:

```
// method in UICollectionView delegate that you need to define.
// update your paging info in method bellow.
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    ...    
}
```

**Remarks:**

Methods that deal with scroll view that i've listed are inherited by `UICollectionViewDelegate` from `UIScrollViewDelegate`. `UICollectionView` itself derived from `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

Comment: This ended up working great! Thank you! One part I don't quite understand is the sticky scrolling - _if_ you're up for it and feel like elaborating on it I would be very appreciative. If not, that's ok! Thanks anyways!

Comment: Ive been reading up and it seems I can use `targetContentOffset.memery.x` to find where the scrolling will land... but I'm unsure about how to move the closest cell in to center view with that information?

Comment: @Keenles I figured it out! I set a `collectionOffset = 0`, and then on `scrollViewWillEndDragging` I checked if the `targetContentOffset.memory.x` was greater than `collectionOffset + 255`, if it was then set targetContentOffset and collectionOffset to `collectionOffset + 255`.. etc etc

Comment: @JodyHeavener Can you please share with me the code you wrote for this. I am trying to have the same thing done for my practice app but i can't get it done. If you can share with me the code, that would be great.