# UIPageViewController negative spacing between pages

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, ios7.1

I have a UIPageViewController set up like this:

```
pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: [UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey: -100])
```

each page in that controller is another uipageviewcontroller. What I am trying to do is have part of the next page or view slightly visible on the side of the screen. I also want the previous page to be slightly visible as well. I have tried setting the spacing key to a negative value but that doesn't seem to work... how can I have negative spacing between pages in a uipageviewcontroller?

Comment: I got the solution this link can help us  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25713998/472336